# Transactional Emails modification

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, transactional-mail

How can i modify transactional mails in Magento?

I want to change the email content.

- The emails are not listed in `system->transactional emails` list.
- I have checked `app/code/locale` too. But I didn't find the email templates to edit.

Comment: Did you manage to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 7):

Go to System > Transactional Emails.

then Click on Add New Template

then in Load Default Template > Choose template from drop-down

then click on load template.

then In Template Information enter new template name.

then u can change the content of template.

I am explaining above scenario by using following example.

Ex. If u want to change email template for "new account creation", then load "New Account" template and edit it and save it.

Then Go to System > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration

Click on Create New Account Option

In Default Welcome Email section select new template from drpdown and save it.

Dats it.....

Answer (score 6):

The emails are located in `app/locale/[language]/email/`. You can choose to edit them there or copy them to `System > Transactional emails`

To copy them to `transactional emails` follow these steps

1. In the email grid click on `new template`
2. Choose the email you want to copy from the *template* dropdown
3. Choose the language you want to copy from the *locale* dropdown
4. Click *load template*

And you're ready to go!

Comment: Also remember to update whatever admin (or other configuration) tells the system to use the transactional email template rather than the file based template.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a step but you are in the right place. You need to

1. Go to System > Transactional Email
2. Choose your transactional email from the drop down and click 'load template'
3. You may now edit the template and save. This will create a new transactional email that you can then assign to a system email in magento configuration area.

You can see a full article on editing default transactional emails or creating your own transactional emails and assigning them in the configuration dashboard on this article in the link below: [HOW TO CUSTOMIZE OR CREATE MAGENTO TRANSACTIONAL EMAIL TEMPLATES AND ASSIGN THEM TO SPECIFIC ACTIONS IN MAGENTO](http://www.sandiego-web.com/magento-setup-and-configuration/how-to-customize-or-create-magento-transactional-email-templates-and-assign-them-to-specific-actions-in-magento/)