# how disable automatic send mail confirmation ORDER in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

How disable automatic send mail confirmation ORDER in magento ? 
but i can send manually order email with button SEND MAIL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to **System> Configuration > sales > sales emails** , than you can see as below image. change **No from yes** and , click on **save config**

[image]

so now order emails will not send.

if you want to send manually, go to **sales > orders> section**, click on particular order , than you can see as below image, select **Notify customer by email** checkbox &  just click on **submit comment** button

[image]

Comment: Ok, order emails will not send, But send manually not send ?

Comment: @TobiDSN please check also for `sending emails manually to particular email` and if works feel free to accept an answer.....

Comment: OK, Send Email Update "Your order #145000047 has been updated to: Payment". Why not detail order ?

Comment: @TobiDSN sorry, i did't got what you are saying, please explain what you are trying and when & where you got that messsage `Your order #145000047 has been updated to: Payment". Why not detail order ?`

Comment: Details order was not delivered to the customer, who sent only update with comment. I want to send a detail of orders.

Comment: @TobiDSN for that you need to use the content of `order email` in `order comments email`, better solution is you need to create  new transactional email , [check this link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/transactional-emails-modification) for creating `new transactional email`

Comment: @TobiDSN once you create `new transactional email` you can select that in `Order Comment Email Template` under `ystem> Configuration > sales > sales emails> order comment emails`  i am going to lunch now & will come guide you clearly....

Comment: ok, Thanks very much, what about the order comment feature itself ?

Comment: @TobiDSN if you want that order comment feature , than you can again change the `email template` under `system> Configuration > sales > sales emails> order comment email` and send comments, one more option is you can use `invoice comments or `credit memo comments` instead of `order comment` part....