# New Order Email - Need to change payment information font

Tags: email-templates, order-confirmation, fonts

We send out a New Order Confirmation and the font size of the credit card information and Processed amount are too big, I like to change the font size.
I have tried to do this in the Magento Admin panel but the change does not take effect.

The order confirmation show "Payment Method" and then below that shows the:
 Credit Card type:
 Credit card Number:  (Last four digits)
 Processed Amount:

Comment: Please include the Magento version you are using as a tag... the answers could be different for Magento 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change it from `transaction email` section.

If you have customised default new order email template then you can simply go to `System > Transactional Email` then open the new order template then find the `Payment Method` section and add **inline css**.

For ex:

```
 ///head part
 <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Payment Method:</th>

 //// body part
 <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">{{var payment_html}}</td>
```

**If you have't customised the template then you can create one and add inline css**. [Learn how to add transactional email here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44578/transactional-emails-modification).

**OR** you can simply add inline css in default template in `app/locale/[your_language]/template/email/sales/order_new.html`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see that in the coding they are using the Inline css, I not sure how this works? 
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

Comment: For header, you will need to change in `app/locale/[your_language]/template/email/html/header.html`

Comment: I was able to understand the use of the inlineCSS file, and some changes are going into affect.